# HTML Table - Put everything without this newline

Tags: html, html-table

```
<body>
    <table border=0>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" rowspan="8"><img src="Start3.bmp"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c35"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c35"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c35"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c35"></td>
            <td class="default" style="border-bottom:dotted;" align="center"><img src="savecell.bmp"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c34"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c34"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c34"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c34"></td>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c33"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c33"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c33"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c33"></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c36"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c36"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c36"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c36"></td>
            <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f1"></td>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c32"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c32"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c32"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c32"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c37"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c37"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c37"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c37"></td>
            <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f2"></td>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c31"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c31"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c31"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c31"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c38"></td>
            <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f3"></td>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c30"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c30"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c30"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="startp3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c39"></td>
            <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f4"></td>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="savecell.bmp"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c29"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c29"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c29"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c40"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c40"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c40"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c40"></td>
            <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f5"></td>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c28"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c41"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c41"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c41"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c41"></td>
            <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f6"></td>
            <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c28"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" rowspan="8"><img src="Start2.bmp"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

The problem is that in this table, in the last lines (4th from last) the TD element should appear next to the rest of the table, but it appears below everything, and I can't get it to be next to the other elements. How can I do that?

edit: I tried putting another tr and td elements to the part that appears in the right side, it appeared below as well, then augmented rowspan Start3.bmp's (at the very first lines) value by 1, the new element appeared along with them, but I cant find a value to put the trouble part too.

Answer (score 0):

The table violates the HTML table model, as you can see by validating it using an HTML5 doctype string. All bets are off then.

The question does not describe the intended structure *or* rendering of the data, so I cannot suggest any specific approach.

You should draw a picture of the desired layout, then design a valid table or design CSS styling that achieves the layout. If you need help with this, you should post a new question, with sufficient verbal explanations and images to show the desired rendering.

Answer (score 0):

By temporarily using `<table border=1px>` you can see your rows and columns defined more clearly, which might be helpful.

You need to declare table cells in the order that they first appear on the page, starting with the top left, then moving to the right, then down one row, and so on. If you want one element to appear along the entire height of the table, you need to declare it in the top row after the `<td>`s you want it to appear to the right of, and then set its `rowspan` the the number of rows in the table.

Is this kind of what you had in mind?

```
<html>
 <body>
 <table border=0>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="7"><img src="Start3.bmp"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c35"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c35"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c35"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c35"></td>
        <td class="default" style="border-bottom:dotted;" align="center"><img src="savecell.bmp"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c34"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c34"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c34"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c34"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c33"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c33"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c33"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c33"></td>
        <td rowspan="7"><img src="Start2.bmp"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c36"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c36"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c36"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c36"></td>
        <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f1"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c32"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c32"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c32"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c37"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c37"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c37"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c37"></td>
        <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f2"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c31"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c31"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c31"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c31"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c38"></td>
        <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f3"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c30"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c30"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c30"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="startp3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c39"></td>
        <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f4"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="savecell.bmp"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c39"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c29"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c29"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c29"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c40"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c40"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c40"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c40"></td>
        <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f5"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c28"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c41"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c41"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c41"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c41"></td>
        <td class="savep3" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3f6"></td>
        <td class="default" align="center"><img src="invisible.png" id="p1c38"><img src="invisible.png" id="p2c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p3c28"><img src="invisible.png" id="p4c28"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </table>
  </body></html>
```